# Having trouble writing select statement that returns 1 row for each year that a user alias appears in a query log

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery, insert-update

I am inserting data into a User table from a Query LOG table. In the query log table, user alias appears each time a query is executed. In the Users table, I want the User Alias column to have the user alias for each combination of date and business name that applies to the alias, with no repeating rows. The reason I need this, is because I am creating a visual that needs to reflect the distinct number of users that have executed a query for each business, by year. I also need the ability to slice by alias, business and date. My goal is to have the result look like..

```
User Alias    LOB                Date
Joe           Business 1         2015-01-01
Joe           Business 1         2016-01-01
Carol         Business 1         2015-01-01
Carol         Business 1         2016-01-01
```

Here is the result I am currently getting, with using the statement below.

```
User Alias    LOB                Date
Joe           Business 1         2015-01-01
Carol         Business 1         2015-01-01
```

I am aware that the "DISTINCT" in statement needs to go, but after that, I am stuck.

```
INSERT INTO [DBO].[USERS] ([User Alias], [LOB], [Date])
SELECT DISTINCT [User Alias], [LOB] , ( SELECT TOP 1 [Date] FROM Business) [Date]
FROM Business [LOG]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[Users] [DIM]
    WHERE [LOG].[User Alias] = [DIM].[User Alias]
        AND [LOG].[LOB] = [DIM].[LOB]
        AND [LOG].[Date] = [DIM].[Date]
    )
AND [User Alias] IS NOT NULL
AND [LOB] IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: What is your sql sever version, does it support MERGE?

Comment: 2016. It does support merge

Comment: I should clarify that each row should reflect user, year and business that the query occurs, without repeating the row. A user may execute up to 100 queries on a given day. All I am concerned about is if the user executed a single query on the given year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GROUP BY Year (as well as Alias and LOB) and SELECT the MIN(Date) instead of a TOP 1 subquery.

EDIT:  a more precise example of how to implement my suggestion --

```
INSERT INTO [DBO].[USERS] ([User Alias], [LOB], [Date])
SELECT [User Alias], [LOB] , MIN([Date]) [Date]
FROM Business [LOG]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [dbo].[Users] [DIM]
    WHERE [LOG].[User Alias] = [DIM].[User Alias]
        AND [LOG].[LOB] = [DIM].[LOB]
        AND YEAR([LOG].[Date]) = YEAR([DIM].[Date])
    )
AND [User Alias] IS NOT NULL
AND [LOB] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [User Alias], [LOB] , YEAR([Date])
```

Comment: This approach returns a repeat rows

Comment: How did you implement it?   If done correctly, the SELECT portion will not return any duplicate rows.   See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Also use the YEAR() function in the EXISTS() clause to avoid duplicating rows that are already in the table.

Comment: I implemented it differently. Your approach works beautifully. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick.

```
SELECT distinct [User Alias], [LOB], datepart(yyyy,[Date]) [Date]
FROM Business [LOG] 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[Users] [DIM] 
WHERE [LOG].[User Alias] = [DIM].[User Alias] 
and [LOG].[LOB] = [DIM].[LOB] and [LOG].[Date] = [DIM].[Date]) 
and [User Alias] is not null
and [LOB] is not null
GROUP BY [DATE], [User Alias], [LOB]
```